# Why is "~/" not recognized from node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wanted to set a path to my user folder with "~/".
Why is this not valid in javascript?

Comment: because it's not evaluated by javascript but by the shell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It has nothing to do with JavaScript. Node's file operations just don't expand `~` for you. It's not something that the file system automatically handles, it's something various programs (like your terminal, file manager, etc.) handle. You can get the home directory via [`os.homedir()`](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_homedir).

Answer (score 2):

Tilde expansion is a bash feature that does not necessarily apply dependent on where the software is deployed. It also opens up questions about supporting other operators.

See https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/684